# Whether to stop windows service depending on precondition?

Tags: service, windows-services

Assume we are creating **windows service WS**. WS depends on some network infrastructure(3rd party product). This infrastructure is a precondition of WS work. WS can't do its work without this infrastructure. Assume that WS is configured to start automatically. What WS should do in case infrastructure is not accessible? Should it stop execution? This infrastructure is another services. Those services can become available. In simple case Admin can start needed infrastructure and try to start manually WS again.But if WS runs on Grid of several hundreds of nodes it would be great if local OS will try to start WS in some intervals. We can try to use **"Recovery" feature** of Windows services. Assume that starting phase of WS is lightweight and it's easy to check precondition. So, we can configure "Recovery" feature to try to start WS continually each say 5 minutes. But "Recovery" feature is used by SCM only if service didn't stop voluntarily by its own free will. So, is it good form of using Windows services to use fast fail (fatal) way to stop service so OS will try to restart it with help of "Recovery" feature? Or is there another good practices (or patterns) to achieve the same goal - automatically try to start WS hoping some other network infrastructure becomes available? 
Updated: to narrow the scope of question: this one is about whether to stop starting of service and use Recovery feature or start and poll the availability of services WS depends on. that is simple question: to be or not to be.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good fit for stackoverflow. It's more a design than programming question, and is broad besides  (too many questions in the question).

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit old-school but I believe that programming is not just coding but is broad term including algorithm design, pattern selection and coding. I see a lot of more general questions about best practices with services in stackoverflow. This question is about whether to stop starting of service or start and poll the availability of services WS depends on. I will update question. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to change the title: Whether to stop windows service depending on precondition? Then people will hit this question more often.

Comment: Two pieces of information that affect the answer are 1) how likely is it for the precondition to be false, and 2) can (or must) a human rectify the situation when the precondition fails. If the answer to 1 is that it's likely now and then, and 2 is it rectifies itself without human intervention, then I would not have the service exit when the precondition is not met, or becomes not met some time after start. I would have the service stay running, and check occasionally for the precondition to be met again.

Comment: Also, can the recondition become false some time after startup? If so, is just checking at startup sufficient?

Comment: 1) precondition will likely to be broken at setup of environment - AMQP server or SQL Server is down. config of WS points to this servers 2) Human should rectify this by installing, configuring mentioned servers. When service is marked as started then it seems that it's ok. But it's not - human intervention is required. Admin can be notified about start failure, setup AMQP server. Then WS can be started on Grid automatically by OS Recovery feature.

Comment: Yes - we can encounter connection errors some time after startup. But we can assume that as soon as starting precondition was true (we started) then we think this connection problems are temporary and wait when resources become available again: poll them in loop with sleep.